# Tightening a shower handle with no visible screws

Tags: doors, shower, doorknob

We have a loose shower handle shown in the picture. There's a handle on either side of the glass door and we can see a threaded (3/16"?) rod inside. (The threaded part does not show on the picture.) However, there's no way to get to it. We can't find any way to disassemble the handle.

Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Can you undo an end cap of the vertical bar and withdraw the handle?

Comment: No, I do not believe I can.

Comment: Hmmm... how about the part nearest the glass? It looks like it might not be part of that horizontal bit. Or maybe the handle on the other side of the door is where it disassembles.